# Monotonicity of a Metric Evaluating Code Large Language Models

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives

## Background

The famous [Evaluating Large Language Models Trained on Code](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.03374) from OpenAI proposed the code LLM; GitHub uses it as the code assistant called GitHub copilot. It also proposed a metric that evaluates the performance of new code LLMs:

$$
\mathrm{Pass}@k=\mathbb{E} _ \mathcal{D}\left[ 1 - \frac{\binom{n-c}{k} }{ \binom{n}{k}}  \right]
$$

where $n \geq c > 0$ and $k \geq 0$.

The $\mathrm{Pass}@k$ evaluates the probability of selecting the $c$ functionally correct responses from a total of $n$ responses **should there be** an oracle with $k$ chances.

## Question

I wonder how this metric behaves with different choices of $n$, $c$, and $k$. For example, is this metric monotonic to $n$, $c$, or $k$? If not, how to attain the best value with different choices of $n$, $c$, and $k$?

I know I could easily take the derivative but the expressions I got do not seem to be positive or negative.

So could anyone help me with the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
from sympy import init_printing
from sympy import symbols
from sympy import derive_by_array
from sympy.functions import binomial

init_printing()
n, c, k = symbols("n, c, k", positive=True)

dn = derive_by_array(1 - binomial(n - c, k) / binomial(n, k), n)
dc = derive_by_array(1 - binomial(n - c, k) / binomial(n, k), c)
dk = derive_by_array(1 - binomial(n - c, k) / binomial(n, k), k)
```

Comment: Based on the equation, I feel the metric would be more accurately described as ***expectation** of selecting **at least one of** the $c$ functionally correct responses from a total of $n$ responses should there be an oracle with $k$ chances.* The important difference is that *expectation* (because of the $\mathbb{E}$)  is an average, and since the metric is implied to have only $k$ as input, it seems to be averaging over different choices of $n$ and $c$. Which means we would only need to look at choices of $k$, given a range of $n$ to average over. $c$ would naturally be averaged over $[0,n]$.